# Вопрос по грабу

Tags: php

Ребят, есть сайт `http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=`тут ид анкеты

Допустим, ид: 38014, вот PHP-скрипт граба для ID 38014:

```
<?php
$url = "http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=38014";
$unique_start = "<body>";
$unique_end = "</body>";
function weather($url, $unique_start, $unique_end) {
$code = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/'.preg_quote($unique_start,
'/').'(.*)'.preg_quote($unique_end, '/').'/Us', $code, $match);
return $match[1];
}
echo weather($url, $unique_start, $unique_end); ?>
```

Этот скрипт будет грабить только одну страницу: `http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=38014`

Как сделать такую вещь: `мой_сайт.ру/id=`тут id любой анкеты, т.е. чтобы грабил анкету с того сайта, чей ид я указал..

Вообщем все доходчиво объяснил. Помогите люди добрые - уже весь мозг кипит :(

**Дополнено.**

Поменял URL, получилось следующее:

```
<?PHP 
$ch = curl_init("http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=" . (int)$_GET['id']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Все запускается, только как грабить в curl? С определенного тега до конца? Как я делал в `file_get_contents`, помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: В этом треде происходит что-то страшное.

Comment: Похоже человек нарыл где-то кусок кода, и, не зная языка, пытается его использовать.

Comment: Кхе, так что такого? Функции cURL - есть в интернете, единственное - что я не знаю, так это Грабинг. Вот и обратился за помощью к вам

Comment: Страшно - ничего. Просто Вам нужно поработать с мануалами. В первую очередь - какие-то статьи по азам программирования. Что такое  переменные и функции, для чего и как они используются.

Comment: В этой ветке Вы получили ответ на ваш вопрос, но в упор его не замечаете.

Answer (score 2):

Замени:

```
$url = "http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=38014";
```

на

```
$url = "http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=" . (int)$_GET['id'];
```

И обращайся к своему скрипту (index.php): *мой_сайт.ру/?id=тут id любой анкеты*

**Дополнено.**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$ch = curl_init("http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=" . (int)$_GET['id']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if( !$result ) $error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// $content можно грабить
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
ob_start();
$ch = curl_init("http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=" . (int)$_GET['id']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if( !$result ) $error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// $content можно грабить (// я по старинке )

$fromBodyToBody = substr($content, strpos($content, '<body>')+6);
$fromBodyToBody = substr($fromBodyToBody, 0, strpos($fromBodyToBody, '</body>'));

// вот контент между <body> и </body>
echo $fromBodyToBody;
?>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ.