# Как грабить от тэга до тэга с cURL

Tags: curl, php

Дан код:

```
<?PHP
$ch = curl_init("http://javagala.ru/uinfo/?uid=" . (int)$_GET['id']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Как сделать граб в cURL?
Например чтобы грабил от тега `<body>` до `</body>`, или хотя бы "от такой-то" строки до "такой-то".

 
Или можно в `file_get_contents` - указать с какого браузера ты сейчас сидишь? ( Например Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) )

Дорогие кодеры! Помогите мне, Пожалуйста! :(

Comment: А что такое "граб" ?

Comment: абзац про user agent вообще не понятен..

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в топике [Вопрос по грабу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17640/)

Comment: Я так понял, ему регулярка нужна)

Comment: Да. Так она у него есть в том куске кода, который он показал вначале. Просто там он тянул контент через *file_get_contents*.

Answer (score 1):

Вытаскивает все ссылки с сайта:

```
<?
preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(.+?)".*?>(.+?)</a>#is', $without_other_tags, $text, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($text);
#$without_other_tags - текст страницы
#$text - массив с ссылками
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тебе по видимому нужно часть файла слить(от и до) это возможно реализовать сокетами, в file_get_contents() нельзя указать браузер, опять же сокетом можно.